# How to get the results of C# WebService call that used a custom proxy for the WebService request?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xml-serialization, codedom

I am trying to read/cast/parse into a string the results of a WebService call.

```
               WebMethod method = list.Services[0].Methods[0] as WebMethod;


    if(method != null) 
    {
                Object ResultsObj;
                ResultsObj = new Object();
                ResultsObj = method.Invoke();

                //Returns "WS.GeocodeResponse" needs to be inner values
                results = ResultsObj.ToString();

                //Like to do the following but get error: 
                   //'object' does not contain a definition for 'Results' and no extension
                     // method 'Results' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
                     // found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
               results = ResultsObj.Results[0].ToString();

                //Or, do something like this but get same error
                results = String.Format("Latitude: {0}, Longitude: {1}",
                    ResultsObj.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude,
                    ResultsObj.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude);


                //Tried casting as an XmlDocument but get runtime error:
                //{"Unable to cast object of type 'WS.GeocodeResponse' to type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'."}
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc = (XmlDocument) method.Invoke();
                    results = "do something with doc";

               //Tried looping through array of results but get error:
               // The type or namespace name 'WS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

               foreach(WS.GeocodeResult result in ResultsObj.GetType().Name)
                 {
                     continue;
                 }



              //Tried reverse engineering what Visual Studio does when create Web Reference
                //thanks to clue at http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp 
                        // “That's because the proxy object is actually compiled into the project 
                        //(take a look at \CodeClient\Web References\CodeWebService\CodeWebService.cs 
                        // to see the source for this 'phantom' object that VS generates for you and compiles into your application.”
                //Mine was "Project Name"/Web References/"Webservice Name"/Reference.cs  
                //I.E. ( LatLonVerification/Web References/net.virtualearth.dev/Reference.cs)
                // Renamed it and added "using LatLonVerification.VirtualEarthGeo;" reference to it in this class;
                //then finally tried to cast it to the new object type but got runtime error:
                //{"Unable to cast object of type 'WS.GeocodeResponse' to type 'LatLonVerification.VirtualEarthGeo.GeocodeResponse'."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

               GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = (GeocodeResponse) ResultsObj;
               results = "parse or do something with geocodeResponse";
```

Background:

I need to update a LatLongVerification dll that we created to call a webservice from MS Access via com. Up to a few months ago it was working.

However, the Bing Webservice changed and our IT depts. Firewall changed. Thus, after updating the Webservice by using the Web References method everything worked, when off the corporate network but, not on the corporate network. SoapUI testing tool also bails behind the firewall. However, the Open Source Wizdl  C# .net tool did work from behind firewall.

Consequently, this began the goal to reverse engineer the Wizdl tool (http://wizdl.codeplex.com/ ) to work as a dll instead of a windows forms app.  Which I think a wide variety of Access and Excel people would also love to have.

Of course, in an effort to just get it to work, I have hard coded several aspects (will fix later).   So far I have successfully returned data to an object from the Bing Webservice even on network! Yet, I can’t seem to do the final cast or parse or conversion such that I can output the data in the dll as a string. I am so close, in that I can see the results in the locals debugger window but, so far in that they are un-returnable.

Comment: Was there a reason to not just use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: I thought that option was the same as Web Service Reference. However, after some research Service Reference is newer and perhaps it may not have the firewall issue. I will give it a shot. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: No go, I got it working again OFF Corp Network with new Service Reference method (was tricky needed service reference in test module to work). However, ON Corp Network the Service gets blocked. With wireshark it shows for both of the easier Web Service/Service methods as an attempt to connect directly via TCP where as with the CustomProxy it uses HTTP/XML as the protocal which gets through the Corp Firewall, I just can't read the response.

Comment: The CustomProxyGenerator Class is using CodeDom  ie a Dynamic  source code generator to create the class structures for the webservice calls and reply's. The gotcha I still have is reading the resulting reply class that is dynamically determined and created in an assembly via CodeDom. The propertyGrid control is able to read the results and the debugger can see the objects.  A Screenshot of debugger showing the propertyGrid class named resultsGrid can be found [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/90610728@N06/8228730296/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is relevant or not but, when faced with a secure web service that I could not directly develop against I used fiddler.

First to capture the wsdl file(and I think one other), save them as text files.
Then 'serve' them back up when visual studio requested them during a service update on the dev machine.

http://www.fiddler2.com